# SQL Computed Column from Temp Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I am trying to add a computed column in SQL Server Management Studio using a self-reference to the table.

My columns are as follows:

```
[Employee ID]   [Previous State Date]    [Previous State] 
                [Next State Date]        [Next State]
```

I want to add a column that shows the third state (that happened after the [Next State] column). For example, if someone went from state a -> b -> c, there would be two rows:

```
[Employee 1][1/1/2016][a][1/2/2016][b]
[Employee 1][1/2/2016][b][1/3/2016][c]
```

I want the data to just show:

```
[Employee 1][1/1/2016][a][1/2/2016][b][c]
```

To do so, I created two columns, `[PreviousID]` and `[NextID]` that concatenate state, date, and Employee ID.

I want to use a temp table to bring in a new column of `temp.[Next State] WHERE table.[Next State] = temp.[Previous State]`

When I try this, I get the error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

My code:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM table

ALTER TABLE table 
ADD [Next Next State] AS (SELECT [Next State] 
                          FROM temp  
                          WHERE table.[Next State] = temp.[Previous State])
```

Comment: Can you tag your question with the sql server you're using. Also, it sounds that you need a separate state table to manage these states.

Comment: Tagged. Im using SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: Do you have a primary key for your base table?

Comment: I'm guessing you're [Next State] column is a varchar of some sort. Check this https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ 
Although I still think that reviewing your table structures is the better way to go. If you had a table with just [EmployeeID][Date][State] so you would log the new state it would be much more efficient.

Comment: I get the data extracted from an external source in the format above. When I create another table with just the states, I still get the same error about subqueries when trying to reference it in a computed column

Comment: @AndrewNeeld okay, check the article I added in the previous comment that seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Forget the temp table and use a GROUP BY query with aggregate functions and CTE. Something like:

```
WITH EarliestLastChanges(EmployeeID, EarliestStateChange, LatestStateChange)
AS
(SELECT
    [Employee ID] AS EmployeeID,
    MIN([Previous State Date]) AS EarliestStateChange
    MAX([Next State Date]) AS LatestStateChange
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    [Employee ID])
SELECT
    ELC1.EmployeeID,
    Concatenated field for Earliest from T1,
    Concatenated field for Latest from T2
FROM
   EarliestLastChanges AS ELC1
   JOIN
   table as T1
   ON ELC1.EmployeeID = T1.[Employee ID] AND ELC1.EarliestStateChange = T1.[Previous State Date]
   EarliestLastChanges AS ELC2
   JOIN
   table as T2
   ON ELC2.EmployeeID = T2.[Employee ID] AND ELC2.EarliestStateChange = T2.[Next State Date]
```

I agree with comments above that a redesign would be a better way to go